# correctly declaring buffer for tcp server c++

Tags: c++, malloc, buffer, tcpserver

I am using a tcp server that I wrote for handling inputs into a database. I have a tcp client sitting on a server that sends the filename to a tcp server sitting on a different linux server. once the filename is received the linux server goes into a shared folder and pulls the file then inserts it into the database.

my problem is with correctly declaring the buffer and clearing it to make sure I get the correct filename without any gibberish added or anything removed from it.

right now it is working like this:

```
 char data[1024];
```

which is fine but it does not automatically delete the buffer completely, so i tried to implicitly allocate memory to "data" such as:

```
char *data = (char*) malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
...
free(data);
```

OR

```
char *data = new char[1024]; 
...
delete[] data;
```

For some reason the above two declaration are declaring a buffer of size =8 I got this using

```
sizeof(data);
```

also what I am receiving is only 8 characters long. I am not sure why it is doing this, any help??

**EDIT**

```
char *data = (char*)malloc(1048 * sizeof(char));
if(data==NULL) exit(1);
cout << "DATA Size: " << sizeof(data) << "\n";
int msglen = read(conn, data, sizeof(data));
cout << "Server got " << msglen << " byte message: " << data << "\n";

if(write(conn, &msglen, sizeof(msglen))<0){
    cout << "Failed to write back to the client " << strerror(errno);
}

free(data);
close(conn);
```

Comment: How are you receiving your data? The reason sizeof(data) returns 8 is because data is a pointer, and on a 64-bit system, the size of a pointer will be 8 bytes.

Comment: please see edit to answer your question

Comment: char data[1024]; memory occupied by this will automatically be freed after going out of scope.

Comment: Instead of read(conn, data, sizeof(data)), you should do read(conn, data, 1048) since the final argument is the number of bytes you want to read, and sizeof(data) will return 8 for the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: the above code is all sitting in an infinite loop to accept many connections from the client app, so whenever i send something with 20 chars it will be stored in data the next time i send 10 chars, the last 10 from the previous 20 will still be there

Comment: You could easily precede the read call with a function to zero out the array, such as bzero. You would place the call bzero(data, 1048) before your read call.

Comment: Thanks @AaronOkano that worked, replacing sizeof to 1024 worked. but that broke the acknowldgment which gets send back, do I need to changed sizeof(msglen) to the actual number of bytes for it to send back the message??

Comment: read returns the number of bytes read, which means the number of bytes to send back will be just msglen, not sizeof(msglen).

Comment: FROM MAN PAGE: ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count); sizeof(msglen) is just the buffer size for the write function, &msglen is what I am sending back which is a pointer to msglen... unless i am understanding the '&' wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. size_t is an alias for another integer type, usually an unsigned int.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like that should be right. What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: All works fine now!! thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code.
1) dont use malloc - you flagged your question as c++ - use malloc only when necessary replace it with:

```
const int dataSize = 1024;
char *data = new char[dataSize];
```

2) sizeof(data) when data is char* returns 8 because it returns size of a pointer not an array when you declare data as array sizeof will return bytes occupied by whole array. you should replace you read with:

```
int msglen = read(conn,data,dataSize)
```

3) I assume that u want to write data u've just received back to sender.. Then:
in write function you put sizeof(msglen) as third argument which will (mostly) always return 4. remove sizeof( ).

```
write(conn, data, msglen);
```

after you are done with the data dont forget to clear the memory using:

```
delete[] data;
```

use `delete[]`  always when you assigned memory with `new[]`.

Comment: Don't forget to `delete[] data` and not `delete data` since the allocation used the array was done using `new[]`.

Answer (score 1):

API `write(int socket, char *buf, int len)`;

Code becomes this:

```
write(con, data, msglen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't use the stack (e.g. `char buf[1024]`), using naked pointers is discouraged as bad style and bug prone. Instead, use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and some variant of amanged memory, such as `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

`#include <memory>` and use a `std::shared_ptr<>`, or `std::unique_ptr<>` plus `std::move()` to return the buffer:

```
std::size_t bufSize = 1024;
std::unique_ptr<char[]> myUniqueBuf(new char[bufSize]);
ssize_t msglen = ::read(conn, *myUniqueBuf, bufSize); // return type is ssize_t, not int
return std::move(myUniqueBuf); // If you need to return the buffer

// I think you will probably prefer a shared_ptr<> because it has a copy
// constructor which makes it easier to pass around and return from functions
std::shared_ptr<char[]> mySharedBuf(new char[1024]);
ssize_t msglen = ::read(conn, *mySharedBuf, bufSize); // return type is ssize_t, not int
ssize_t bytesOut = ::write(conn, *mySharedBuf, msglen);
return mySharedBuf;
```

The advantage to `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` is that you don't have to worry about cleaning up a naked pointer (i.e. calling `delete[] data;`) because with managed memory it will happen automatically for you when the buffer handle goes out of scope or the reference count goes to zero (e.g. `myUniqueBuf` or `mySharedBuf`).